# Same input enter is not firing transition

Tags: javascript

I am writing a program where the number of letters you input should call different svg animations.
Below is my example of the input with one letter length. The problem is that if you put the same one letter 
or any other one character once again, transition does not work. I have tryied so many things including 
animation with "from" and "to", but nothing solves the problem.

```js
var TXT = document.getElementById('txtinpt');
var DASH, IDNAME = 'sig1';

TXT.addEventListener("blur", letter);

function letter() {

    document.getElementById(IDNAME).style.transition = "none";
    document.getElementById(IDNAME).style.strokeDashoffset = DASH;

        if (TXT.value.length == 1) {
            document.getElementById('sig1').style.transition = ".8s linear";
            document.getElementById('sig1').style.strokeDashoffset = "0";
            DASH = '900';
            IDNAME = 'sig1';
    }
}
```

```css
#sig1 {
        stroke-dasharray: 900px;
        stroke-dashoffset: 900px;
}
```

```html
<input id="txtinpt" type="text" />

<svg viewBox="-50 50 200 200" width="300" height="180" style="background-color: orange">
        <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" id="sig1" 
        d="m64.5,222.28333c-1,1 -2,1 -4,1c-4,0 -7.513,0.40602 -9,-2c-3.32501,
        -5.37999 -5.99594,-22.86484 -7,-34c-1.34708,-14.93939 0.38828,
        -24.33003 6,-34c3.61945,-6.23694 9.64749,-10.97249 14,-12c1.9465,
        -0.45949 2.29291,-0.70711 3,0c3.53552,3.53554 1,12 1,19c0,5 0,10 0,
        14c0,1 0.57956,0.91418 0,-1c-1.04483,-3.45085 -5.47739,-6.63243 -10,
        -13c-3.3765,-4.75388 -7.39902,-10.8981 -9,-18c-1.33768,-5.93384 -2.68976,
        -10.03406 -2,-16.99999c0.50244,-5.0742 2.31732,-8.31069 11,-12c7.58951,
        -3.22482 13.93796,-6.49829 20,-7c1.99319,-0.16496 2,1 2,3c0,2 -0.17194,
        5.56063 -1,5c-4.45929,-3.01908 -6.47394,-14.22683 -11,-24c-8.08334,
        -17.45451 -14,-25 -18,-29c-1,-1 -1,0 -1,9c0,11 3.33633,32.93664 6,
        48c2.29031,12.95199 3.26926,28.50887 7,37.99999c5.58417,14.20624 11.49622,
        18.90779 12,23c0.12219,0.99251 -0.0535,1.54051 -2,2c-2.17624,0.51375 -5.2771,
        1.77199 -9,0c-4.51468,-2.14885 -7.51373,-2.82375 -7,-5c0.68927,-2.91974 7.8858,
        2.32422 16,5c6.91388,2.27995 13.22836,4.85194 16,6c1.30655,0.5412 1,2 0,2c-2,
        0 -4.0535,1.4595 -6,1c-2.17624,-0.51375 -5.93292,-5.10446 -9,-7c-6.85815,
        -4.23859 -10.08743,-6.79393 -15,-9c-4.07965,-1.83203 -6.29291,-3.70711 -7,
        -3c-1.41422,1.41423 2.75223,4.28316 5,6c6.40714,4.89374 11.01703,6.4124 16,
        6c6.06204,-0.50171 13.57114,-4.38507 19,-10c7.92529,-8.19693 7,-12 7,-14c0,
        -2 -2,-3 -2,-3c-2,0 -2.1731,-0.14726 -3,1c-2.6149,3.62799 -5.96207,13.5372 -11,
        22c-8.38965,14.09303 -17.24722,22.79562 -32,36c-9.5423,8.54077 -23.15686,
        13.57971 -29,16c-2.06586,0.85571 -3,0 -3,-3c0,-7 2.49875,-17.94672 3,-25c0.638,
        -8.97736 -0.01624,-16.20224 6,-24c3.91138,-5.06963 13.47281,-9.96919 25,-12c6.89383,
        -1.21451 19.03406,-2.68976 26,-2c10.14841,1.0049 14.64886,2.19577 17,6c1.05145,
        1.70131 -0.29291,2.29289 -1,3c-0.70709,0.70711 -1,1 -2,1l0,0l-2,0" />
</svg>
```

Comment: condition `if (TXT.value.length == 1)` will be true only for the input of length 1.

Comment: @MysterX says as i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are using `blur` event on the `input` and try to change the entered character by another character (so `TXT.input.length`) will stay `1` when you `click` outside the `input` and the `blur` event occurs, so the transition won't be reflected.

With your actual code you will need to input more than `1` character and then `click` outside the `input`, the transition will be reset, then you reset the input value to `1` character, so the animation can be reproduced.

I think **the best would be to use the `keyup` event, so you can see the animation effects whenever you type on the `input`**.

**Demo:**

```js
var TXT = document.getElementById('txtinpt');
var DASH, IDNAME = 'sig1';

TXT.addEventListener("keyup", letter);

function letter() {

    document.getElementById(IDNAME).style.transition = "none";
    document.getElementById(IDNAME).style.strokeDashoffset = DASH;

        if (TXT.value.length == 1) {
            document.getElementById('sig1').style.transition = ".8s linear";
            document.getElementById('sig1').style.strokeDashoffset = "0";
            DASH = '900';
            IDNAME = 'sig1';
    }
}
```

```css
#sig1 {
        stroke-dasharray: 900px;
        stroke-dashoffset: 900px;
}
```

```html
<input id="txtinpt" type="text" />

<svg viewBox="-50 50 200 200" width="300" height="180" style="background-color: orange">
        <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" id="sig1" 
        d="m64.5,222.28333c-1,1 -2,1 -4,1c-4,0 -7.513,0.40602 -9,-2c-3.32501,
        -5.37999 -5.99594,-22.86484 -7,-34c-1.34708,-14.93939 0.38828,
        -24.33003 6,-34c3.61945,-6.23694 9.64749,-10.97249 14,-12c1.9465,
        -0.45949 2.29291,-0.70711 3,0c3.53552,3.53554 1,12 1,19c0,5 0,10 0,
        14c0,1 0.57956,0.91418 0,-1c-1.04483,-3.45085 -5.47739,-6.63243 -10,
        -13c-3.3765,-4.75388 -7.39902,-10.8981 -9,-18c-1.33768,-5.93384 -2.68976,
        -10.03406 -2,-16.99999c0.50244,-5.0742 2.31732,-8.31069 11,-12c7.58951,
        -3.22482 13.93796,-6.49829 20,-7c1.99319,-0.16496 2,1 2,3c0,2 -0.17194,
        5.56063 -1,5c-4.45929,-3.01908 -6.47394,-14.22683 -11,-24c-8.08334,
        -17.45451 -14,-25 -18,-29c-1,-1 -1,0 -1,9c0,11 3.33633,32.93664 6,
        48c2.29031,12.95199 3.26926,28.50887 7,37.99999c5.58417,14.20624 11.49622,
        18.90779 12,23c0.12219,0.99251 -0.0535,1.54051 -2,2c-2.17624,0.51375 -5.2771,
        1.77199 -9,0c-4.51468,-2.14885 -7.51373,-2.82375 -7,-5c0.68927,-2.91974 7.8858,
        2.32422 16,5c6.91388,2.27995 13.22836,4.85194 16,6c1.30655,0.5412 1,2 0,2c-2,
        0 -4.0535,1.4595 -6,1c-2.17624,-0.51375 -5.93292,-5.10446 -9,-7c-6.85815,
        -4.23859 -10.08743,-6.79393 -15,-9c-4.07965,-1.83203 -6.29291,-3.70711 -7,
        -3c-1.41422,1.41423 2.75223,4.28316 5,6c6.40714,4.89374 11.01703,6.4124 16,
        6c6.06204,-0.50171 13.57114,-4.38507 19,-10c7.92529,-8.19693 7,-12 7,-14c0,
        -2 -2,-3 -2,-3c-2,0 -2.1731,-0.14726 -3,1c-2.6149,3.62799 -5.96207,13.5372 -11,
        22c-8.38965,14.09303 -17.24722,22.79562 -32,36c-9.5423,8.54077 -23.15686,
        13.57971 -29,16c-2.06586,0.85571 -3,0 -3,-3c0,-7 2.49875,-17.94672 3,-25c0.638,
        -8.97736 -0.01624,-16.20224 6,-24c3.91138,-5.06963 13.47281,-9.96919 25,-12c6.89383,
        -1.21451 19.03406,-2.68976 26,-2c10.14841,1.0049 14.64886,2.19577 17,6c1.05145,
        1.70131 -0.29291,2.29289 -1,3c-0.70709,0.70711 -1,1 -2,1l0,0l-2,0" />
</svg>
```